# Set distance between bars in a chart

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to set the distance between the bars in bar chart. I wanna add images as description on every bar so I need a way to place the bars in the centric to the image.

At the moment I use the html as labels but the result is not as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/troynt/KrTbz/3/

```
xAxis: {
  tickLength: 0,
  lineWidth: 0,
  categories: ['Awesome', 'Awesome Previous'],
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  labels: {
    //                    enabled: false,
    color: '#fff',
    x: 5,
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function () {
      return {
        'Awesome': '<img class="" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x200/ff6600/ffffff"/>',
        'Awesome Previous': '<img class="" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x200/ff3300/ffffff"/>',
        'Good': '<img class="" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x200/ff6644/ffffff"/>'
      }[this.value];
    }
  }
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only way is to set the height of the chart, which is in this case the 3 times the height of the images plus some padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.groupPadding) / [pointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointPadding) parameters.